# Javascript Regex: negative lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace in a formula all floating numbers that miss the preceding zero. Eg:

"4+.5" should become: "4+0.5"

Now I read look behinds are not supported in JavaScript, so how could I achieve that? The following code also replaces, when a digit is preceding:

```js
var regex = /(\.\d*)/,
formula1 = '4+1.5',
formula2 = '4+.5';

console.log(formula1.replace(regex, '0$1')); //4+10.5
console.log(formula2.replace(regex, '0$1')); //4+0.5
```

Comment: Try `.replace(/\B\.\d/g, '0$&')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
s = s.replace(/\B\.\d/g, '0$&')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eMx9fR/1).

**Details**

- `\B\.` - matches a `.` that is either at the start of the string or is not preceded with a word char (letter, digit or `_`)
- `\d` - a digit.

The `0$&` replacement string is adding a `0` right in front of the whole match (`$&`).

JS demo:

```js
var s = "4+1.5\n4+.5";
console.log(s.replace(/\B\.\d/g, '0$&'));
```

Another idea is by using an alternation group that matches either the start of the string or a non-digit char, capturing it and then using a backreference:

```js
var s = ".4+1.5\n4+.5";
console.log(s.replace(/(^|\D)(\.\d)/g, '$10$2'));
```

The pattern will match

- `(^|\D)` - Group 1 (referred to with `$1` from the replacement pattern): start of string (`^`) or any non-digit char
- `(\.\d)` - Group 2 (referred to with `$2` from the replacement pattern): a `.` and then a digit

Comment: Thanks, the 2nd solution works just fine! Version 1 does not work, since it is possible that the dot is preceeded by letters of functions (eg "ln.05")

Comment: @Beppe Glad it worked for you. Note that without `^` alternative, a `.5` number at the start of the string would not have been changed to `0.5`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex `(\D)(\.\d*)`

```js
var regex = /(\D)(\.\d*)/,
formula1 = '4+1.5',
formula2 = '4+.5';

console.log(formula1.replace(regex, '$10$2'));
console.log(formula2.replace(regex, '$10$2'));
```